# PageDown output as HTML unexpected token ;

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagedown

I'm trying to show the results from my PageDown textarea on the show view in rails.
The example I am following is here:
http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var converter = new Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
document.write(converter.makeHtml("<%= j @joboffer.tasks.to_s %>");
</script>
```

However, there is a javascript error, stating that ; is unexpected.
My output, shortened, looks like this:

```
..(converter.makeHtml("Aufgaben  \n\n - Zusatzleistungen\n          ");
```

It doesn't really matter what I insert into the database, the code gets accepted during edit, but nothing whatsoever is shown in show. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. Forgot to close one more bracket before the last ;
Time for bed.

Also, there is a typo in the PageDown documentation:

```
document.write(converter.makeHtml("<script>alert(42);</script><b>bold");
```

Missing one ) towards the end at the sanitizer example:
http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown